# background-image css clicavel. Tem como?

Tags: css, html5

tem como fazer um background-image css clicável?

**Segue o código que tenho:**

```
position: relative;
width:140px;
font-family: Arial, Verdana; 
font-size: 15px; 
padding: 5px; 
background-image:url(../../img/buscar-icon.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:right;
```

Comment: Com javascript é possível,

Comment: de que forma???

Comment: Clicável como? O que é para acontecer no clique? Qualquer elemento é clicável, mas a imagem de background em si não é.

Answer (score 3):

Talvez você esteja falando de adicionar isso ao css:

```
cursor:pointer
```

Se precisar acrescentar uma ação apenas quando o click é executado, então utilize `:active`

```
.element:active{}
```

Exemplo:

```css
.clicavel{
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   background-color: lime;
   cursor: pointer;
   transition: background-color 400ms ease;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   display: flex;
   text-align: center;
}

.clicavel:active{
     background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="clicavel">
   Clique e segure
</div>
```